# Removing period from a number

Tags: c#, jquery, regex

Hi I have a regex expression that takes a number and removes all the commas and other characters from it.

```
     num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g, '');
```

I need to add to this regexpression so it also removed dots from it. For example 23.00 it should return 23 only. I tried to this ("//.",/\$|\,/g, '') but didn't work well.

Please let me know how to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: If it's 23.5 should it return 235 or 23?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't altering the number by rounding it or truncating it before turning it into a string?

Comment: And something like "123.345,56" should become???? Calling `ToString` without culture info may get you in trouble...

Comment: Could you explain what is the purpose of the C# tag?

Comment: if it is 23.5 it should return 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For matching a dot (which is a pecial character) use a back slash to escape it.. Try something like:

```
 num = num.toString().replace(/\$\.|\,/g, '');
```

**UPDATE**

According to your last comment you don't want the text after the period..
If it's really a number `Math.Floor(num).ToString()` should do the job.

If it doesn't have to be a number and you still want to use regular expression:

```
 num = num.toString().replace(/\..*/, '');
```

If you are not committed to regex:

```
 num = int.Parse(num.ToString().Split('.')[0]); // In case num is a number, otherwise, int.Parse and ToString are not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do this, and avoid the regexes? `num.Floor().ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) it looks like `.ToString("F0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` would take a double like 18934.1879 and output 18934.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need RegEx:

```
string num = myNumber.ToString().Replace("$","").Replace(".","").Replace(",","");
```

This is assuming you want a number, such as "123.45" to be "12345" and not "123"

If you want "123.45" to be "123", use this instead:

```
string num = String.Format("{0:#.##}", myNumber).Replace(",","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num = num.replace('.', '')
```

If you insist on using regex, place a \ before the period. This makes the period a literal rather than a regex pattern.